# C# CS8025 Parsing Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm wondering if someone can help me figure out the error in the following script. Here is the error:

Assets/Scripts/PlayerInput.cs(1,37): error CS8025: Parsing error

Any help would be appreciated. The code is below.

```
private class GridManager gridManager;
public LayerMask Tiles;
private GameObject activeTile;

void Awake ()
{
    gridManager = GetComponent();
}
    void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        if (ActiveTile == null)
            SelectTile ();
        else
            AttemptMove ();
    }
}

void SelectTile ()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit2D hit = GetRayIntersection(ray, 50f, Tiles);
    if (hit)
        activeTile = hit.collider.gameObject;
}

void AttemptMove ()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit2D hit = GetRayIntersection(ray, 50f, Tiles);
    if (hit)
    {
        if (NeighborCheck (hit.collider.gameObject)
        {
                    activeTile.GetComponent().Move(hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position);
                hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent().Move(activeTile.transform.position);
            gridManager.CheckMatches();
            }
            }
            }

            bool NeighborCheck (GameObject objectToCheck)
            {
                int xDifference = Mathf.Abs     (activeTile.transform.position.x - objectToCheck.transform.position.x);
                int yDifference = Mathf.Abs (activeTile.transform.position.y - objectToCheck.transform.position.y);

                if (xDifference + yDifference == 1)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }

            // Move script
            private GridManager gridManager;

            void Awake ()
            {
                gridManager = GetComponent();
            }

            public void Move (Vector2 destination)
            {
                transform.position = destination; // provisional
            }
```

Comment: That is not the whole script, for a parse error to be fixed, the whole script is needed since you are most likely missing a curly brace somewhere. This is quite common issue, I would guess you did not really search before posting coz you'd got a hell of a lot of answers for this. If that is the whole script then you need to learn C# first coz you are missing the knowledge on how to declare a class.

Comment: The very first line in your code snippet is wrong.  `private class GridManager gridManager;`  You can't "declare" a class.  Also, _please_, format your code, not just for our sake, but for your own.

Answer (score 1):

When you have 1 error in your code, you stop and fix it before moving on. You have more than 10 compiler errors in your code. I was able able to get the code to compile after heavily modifying it. Please take **#9** seriously.

1. Change  `if (ActiveTile == null)` to  `if (activeTile == null)`.
2. Change  `GetRayIntersection(ray, 50f, Tiles);` from `SelectTile()` and `AttemptMove()` functions to `Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(ray, 50f, Tiles);`
3. Change  `gridManager = GetComponent();` from  `Awake()` function to  `gameObject.GetComponent<GridManager>();`
4. Change `Mathf.Abs(activeTile.transform.position.x - objectToCheck.transform.position.x);` and `Mathf.Abs(activeTile.transform.position.y - objectToCheck.transform.position.y);`

   to

   `Mathf.Abs((int)(activeTile.transform.position.x - objectToCheck.transform.position.x));
   Mathf.Abs((int)(activeTile.transform.position.y - objectToCheck.transform.position.y));`
5. Change `activeTile.GetComponent().Move(hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position);` and
   `hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent().Move(activeTile.transform.position);`

   to

   `activeTile.GetComponent<CharacterController>().Move(hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position);

   hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>().Move(activeTile.transform.position);`
6. Add '`)`' to the end of `if (NeighborCheck (hit.collider.gameObject)`
   So you should have  `if (NeighborCheck(hit.collider.gameObject))`
7. Change `private class GridManager gridManager;` to  `private GridManager gridManager;`
8. Change `gridManager = GetComponent();` in the `Awake()` function  to  `gridManager = GetComponent<GridManager>();`
9. **FINALLY, STOP COPY AND PASTE AND LEARN C#.**

You whole code should look like something below.

```
public class PlayerInput : MonoBehaviour
{

    private GridManager gridManager;
    public LayerMask Tiles;
    private GameObject activeTile;

    void Awake()
    {
        gridManager = GetComponent();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            if (activeTile == null)
                SelectTile();
            else
                AttemptMove();
        }
    }

    void SelectTile()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(ray, 50f, Tiles);
        if (hit)
            activeTile = hit.collider.gameObject;
    }

    void AttemptMove()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(ray, 50f, Tiles);
        if (hit)
        {
            if (NeighborCheck(hit.collider.gameObject))
            {
                activeTile.GetComponent<CharacterController>().Move(hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position);
                hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>().Move(activeTile.transform.position);
                gridManager.CheckMatches();
            }
        }
    }

    bool NeighborCheck(GameObject objectToCheck)
    {
        int xDifference = Mathf.Abs((int)(activeTile.transform.position.x - objectToCheck.transform.position.x));
        int yDifference = Mathf.Abs((int)(activeTile.transform.position.y - objectToCheck.transform.position.y));

        if (xDifference + yDifference == 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


    void Awake()
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<GridManager>();
    }

    public void Move(Vector2 destination)
    {
        transform.position = destination; // provisional
    }
}
```